# CMake error "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5QuickControls2""

Tags: debian, kde, qt, cmake

I'm trying to [build the vvave music player](https://github.com/KDE/vvave#build-for-desktop) on Debian11/KDE but running `cmake ..` fails - it shows this error:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

When I run `CXX="gcc" sudo cmake ..` it returns:

```
Installing in /usr/local. Run /home/username/vvave/build/prefix.sh to set the environment for vvave.
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5QuickControls2"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5QuickControls2Config.cmake
    qt5quickcontrols2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5QuickControls2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "Qt5QuickControls2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "Qt5QuickControls2" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)
```

despite having the packages needed for Ubuntu (see the linked Readme) installed. Package `Qt5QuickControls2` is installed too.

Asking here partly because [there still is no way to report bugs/issues of vvave](https://phabricator.kde.org/T7888).

Comment: The GCC C++ compiler is `g++`, not `gcc`. You should not need `sudo` for any other step than `make install`, as mentioned in the project's documentation that you link to.

Comment: I also tried it with g++ (`CXX="/usr/bin/g++"`) and got the same error when I run it with sudo. When I run it without sudo (which I tried first) I get lots of permission denied problems like `CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:223 (file): file failed to open for writing (Permission denied): /home/username/vvave/build/CMakeFiles/3.18.4/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp`

Comment: You get permission errors because you have already tried running with `sudo` once before, which created files and directories owned by root. Clear out your repository, clone it again and re-build (following the exact instructions).

Comment: If I follow the exact instructions (including cloning the repo) after deleting the folder I get the `No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found` error I put above. When I run `CXX="g++" cmake ..` or `CXX="/usr/bin/g++" cmake ..` I get the second error.

Comment: On Ubuntu at least, `Qt5QuickControls2Config.cmake` appears to be provided by the `qtquickcontrols2-5-dev` package

Comment: Now it returns `By not providing "FindMauiKit.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "MauiKit", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "MauiKit" with any of the following names: MauiKitConfig.cmake mauikit-config.cmake` I guess one has to wait until Maui is available on Debian?

Comment: ? "FindMauiKit.cmake" : Maybe https://github.com/mauikit/mauikit